# Why is execution times measured differently here using Java?

Tags: java, long-integer, execution-time

What is the difference between these 2? They both give me the execution-times with slighlty different values and I can tell they are written differently. But since the outcome is nearly identical, what does code 2 do that code 1 does not? What actually is the function of "sum" and is it even executed?

Code 1:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    long n0 = System.nanoTime();
    long n1 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(" resolution " + (n1 - n0) + " nanoseconds");
    }
```

Code 2:

```
int[] given = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        long t0 = System.nanoTime();
        sum += given[i];
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(" resolution " + (t1 - t0) + " nanoseconds");
    }
```

Here is the output for those who asked:

Code 1:

[image]

Code 2:
[image]

Comment: One is calculating the sum of an array and the other one isn't?

Comment: Well, code 2 does a little bit more, as it sums up an array of integers. Can you share the times that you see?

Comment: Can you share the output?

Comment: If *feels* like you're trying to write a microbenchmark (or some equivalent code). This is **very tricky** to get right and as  good start you should [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java). **tl;dr** use existing frameworks and don't try to build your own, you're almost guaranteed to get plenty of details wrong.

Comment: Also, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply code to try out `System.nanoTime()`. Doing something or nothing between two calls does not make a discernible difference. The resolution of the clock is about 100 ns.

As `sum` is not printed, the compiler might have optimized the code by removing just that extra code.

Furthermore it seems that nanoTime alone already requires ~100 ns.

---

***Note***
The code is primarily written for ones own curiosity.